# javamail throwing javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: text/related; charset=UTF-8

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to create an EML back (using javamail) from a proprietary archive format.  I get the following error:

> "javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: text/related; charset=UTF-8"

I have searched in RFC but couldn't figure out if this violates.  The source email content has the boundary parameter mentioned below.

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
boundary=_861f0215-a7a4-4ec2-84ea-56b5552629ae_; type="text/html"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

If I replace the whole Content-Type with Content-Type: text/html, then it works.

Comment: The Content-Type clearly says "multipart/related".  I have no idea why the error message would say "text/related" unless there's some other part of the message you're not showing us.  But...  I don't understand exactly what it is you're trying to do.  Are you trying to read the email message and do something with the content of the message?  Do you understand what a multipart/related message is, and how to interpret the parts of the message?